# Root filesystem full because /platform directory

Tags: solaris, disk-cleanup

I have a solaris 10 server.
The / filesystem is full beacuse the /platform directory.
What type of files resides in that directory? Can I delete those files?

Comment: I doubt the contents of `/platform` are what's causing your root partition to be full unless someone did something disastrously wrong.  Post the output from `df -h` and `du -skdh /*`

Comment: why do you say /platform is full? share the output as asked by Andrew Henle

Answer (score 1):

/platform should have all the various links and files for hardware specific systems(servers).  I would not expect this to be very large.  On two different Solaris 10 servers, one is 349M, the other 317M.

The only reason I can envision it being larger is if someone was trying to make an image that might support multiple CPU archs?

What size are you seeing in your /platform?  `du -sh /platform`

Is root and var separate?  `df -h / /var`?  If / is full, you're going to have issues on your hands.